# How to pass parameters spring batch Intellij maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm reading a spring batch book and making the examples that show because I will start to work with java and spring batch the next month(now I use c#), one example uses `ParameterValidator` to validate receiving one parameter  `name` so the `maven test` will work only if the parameter it was past,

```
 public class ParameterValidator implements JobParametersValidator {
        @Override
        public void validate(JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
        String fileName = parameters.getString("fileName");
        if(!StringUtils.hasText(fileName)) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("fileName missing");
        }
        else if(!StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(fileName, "csv")) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("fileName parameter does " +
                    "not use the csv file extension");
        }
    }
```

I tried passing the data using arguments tag in `pom.xml`:

```
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <arguments> fileName=foo.csv</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

, editing the test:

[image: test configuration maven]

and try other answers I found on internet but always raise the error of missing parameter.

Is it possible to pass arguments using this IDE and `maven`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set JobParameters in spring batch with spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557623/how-do-i-set-jobparameters-in-spring-batch-with-spring-boot)

Comment: I know how to pass parameters when I have a .jar file from cmd, but when I run the lyfecycle in the ide I can't go beyond the test because it gives me an error and I can't create it.  
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException: fileName missing`  
I guess there must be a way either by editing the test run on the lifecycle or through pom.xml to pass a parameter but I can't find it

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass in command line argument through args[] passed to main function and call CommandLineJobRunner.main(args) as if you are executing from cmd