# How to pass data into spring batch ItemProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a CSV file that contains records of data (cases), for which I created a `caseDTO` object , however some of the properties of the `caseDTO` must be field from data included in the file name (every file must has a name with strict structure that contains some data).

What i want to achieve is to pass the data included in the file name to the item processor where i will append this data into every `caseDTO` before passing it to the item writer.

Does any one knows how to pass data to a step `itemProcessor` when I launch the job from the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to pass filename as job parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557623/how-do-i-set-jobparameters-in-spring-batch-with-spring-boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution is to set the dynamic parameters in the job parameters so the step's writer , processor , reader can have access to it . by injecting their values as following

`@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") public void setFileName(final String name) { //... }`