# Spring Batch doesn't update Job repository after force termination

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm using SpringBoot 2.4.x app with SpringBatch 4.3.x. I've created a simple job.
Where I've FlatFileItemReader which reads from CSV file. I've ImportKafkaItemWriter which writes to Kafka topic. One step where I combines these. I'm using SimpleJobLauncher and I've set ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as TasKExecutor of the JobLauncher. It is working fine as I've expected. But one resilience use case I've which is if I kill the app and then restart the app and trigger the job then it would carry on and finish the remaining job. Unfortunately it is not happening. I did further investigate and found that when I forcibly close the app SpringBatch job repository key tables look like this:

| job_execution_id | version | job_instance_id | create_time | start_time | end_time | status | exit_code | exit_message | last_updated | job_configuration_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-06-16 09:32:43 | 2021-06-16 09:32:43 |  | STARTED | UNKNOWN |  | 2021-06-16 09:32:43 |  |

and

| step_execution_id | version | step_name | job_execution_id | start_time | end_time | status | commit_count | read_count | filter_count | write_count | read_skip_count | write_skip_count | process_skip_count | rollback_count | exit_code | exit_message | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | productImportStep | 1 | 2021-06-16 09:32:43 |  | STARTED | 3 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | EXECUTING |  | 2021-06-16 09:32:50 |

If I manually update these tables where I set a valid end_time and status to FAILED then I can restart the job and works absolutely fine. May I know what I need to do so that Spring Batch can update those relevant repositories appropriately and I can avoid this manual steps. I can provide more information about code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I manually update these tables where I set a valid end_time and status to FAILED then I can restart the job and works absolutely fine. May I know what I need to do so that Spring Batch can update those relevant repositories appropriately and I can avoid this manual steps

When a job is killed abruptly, Spring Batch won't have a chance to update its status in the Job repository, so the status is stuck at `STARTED`. Now when the job is restarted, the only information that Spring Batch has is the status in the job repository. By just looking at the status in the database, Spring Batch cannot distinguish between a job that is effectively running and a job that has been killed abruptly (in both cases, the status is `STARTED`).

The way to go in indeed manually updating the tables to either mark the status as `FAILED` to be able to restart the job or `ABANDONED` to abandon it. This is a business decision that you have to make and there is no way to automate it on the framework side. For more details, please refer to the reference documentation here: [Aborting a Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a faked parameter example Version a counter to increment for every new job execution so  you don't have to check for the table database job.

What I mean mvn clean package
Then you try to launch the program like this :
`java my-jarfile.jar dest=/tmp/foo Version="0"`
`java my-jarfile.jar dest=/tmp/foo Version="1"`
`java my-jarfile.jar dest=/tmp/foo Version="2"`
etc ... Or
You Can use jobParameters to launch thé job programatically via jobLauncher and use date paramèter date = new Date().toString() which gives date with New stamp on every New job execution

Comment: I forget to mention how to set jobparameters in spring batch with spring boot please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557623/how-do-i-set-jobparameters-in-spring-batch-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

You can use "JVM Shutdown Hook":
Something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    if (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
        jobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
        jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
        jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
        jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
    }
}));
```